# Content Organiser prevents workflow autostart and shows System Account

Tags: workflow, content-organizer

I'm hoping someone can help with an issue I have with Content Organiser.

I have a document library that has a SPD ootb approval workflow and using Content organiser.

The first problem was that the workflow (any workflow) refused to autostart. Apparently, this is a know issue to microsoft and hasnt been resolved. So I found a feature on codplex that someone developed. http://sp2010workflowfix.codeplex.com/

The second problem is that though the workflow now starts, it starts under 'System Account'. The Approval Workflow contains many instance of 'workflow:Initiator' which I have now changed to CreatedBy so emails can be sent.

Does anyone have a proper fix to this, though http://sp2010workflowfix.codeplex.com/ works it has limitations as the 'Modified By' shows system account.

If anyone has any ideas on how to resolve I would be greatful.

Comment: Do you have wsp of this project i can no longer extract wsp?